# Unable to establish a connection to clrdbg when deploy tizen xamarin application to real watch

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, tizen, samsung

Please help to solve with error

"unable to start debugging. unable to establish a connection to clrdbg"

VS 2022 C# and xaml deploy to real samsung watch 3 it work good in emulation

Thanks you so much
[enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXSj6.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for updating it here.
What version is your "Visual Studio Tools for Tizen"?
3.7.0.0 is the latest version.
I think that you have not installed it fully
Could you uninstall it and then try to install it again?
Thanks